# Initialize BIO variable with NSData bytes on iphone

Tags: ios, openssl, nsdata

I have to validate receipts from In-App Purchases inside an iPhone application (iOS 7 only).
Unfortunately, cryptography, openssl and In-App Purchases are completely new for me so I have some problems to get them working.
I'm following the guide provided by Apple to verify receipts locally and I included openssl in my project as static library. This is the code provided by Apple to verify receipt signature using OpenSSL:

```
BIO *b_receipt;
BIO *b_x509;

PKCS7 *p7 = d2i_PKCS7_bio(b_receipt, NULL);

X509_STORE *store = X509_STORE_new();
X509 *appleRootCA = d2i_X509_bio(b_x509, NULL);
X509_STORE_add_cert(store, appleRootCA);

BIO *b_receiptPayload;
int result = PKCS7_verify(p7, NULL, store, NULL, b_receiptPayload, 0);
if (result == 1)
{
    // Receipt signature is Valid
    // b_receiptPayload contains the payload
}
```

I use this code to get the receipt and the certificate:

```
NSData *receiptData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]];
NSData *certificateData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"AppleIncRootCertificate" withExtension:@"cer"]];
```

How can I use these two `NSData` to initialize `BIO` variables `b_receipt` and `b_x509`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_s_mem.html:

```
BIO *BIO_new_mem_buf(void *buf, int len);
```

creates a read-only memory BIO object from a given buffer. In your case

```
BIO *b_receipt = BIO_new_mem_buf((void *)[receiptData bytes], (int)[receiptData length]);
```

The data is read directly from the supplied buffer. If `receiptData` is valid as long
as `b_receipt` is used, you need not copy the data.

`BIO_new_mem_buf()` does not modify the buffer, therefore you can safely add a
`void *` cast to avoid a "Passing 'const void *' to parameter of type 'void *' discards qualifiers" warning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I get this warning on [receiptData bytes]: Passing 'const void *' to parameter of type 'void *' discards qualifiers... Any ideas how to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Solved this warning using: void *receiptBytes = malloc([receiptData length]); [receiptData getBytes:receiptBytes length:[receiptData length]]; Thank you so much!

Comment: @matteodv: You need not copy the data if the BIO object is used only while the NSData object is valid. In that case you can avoid the compiler warning with an explicit cast. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @matteodv: If the answer helped it would be nice if you "accept" it.